# How to create a mobile-responsive theme for Blogger with HTML codes for a full-sized header, html widgets at the bottom, and nav bar?

Tags: html, mobile, widget, navbar, blogger

I'm manually making my Blogger theme responsive, and so far, it's okay already. My only 3 problems are the header, the html widgets, and the navbar.

1. My header is full screen on desktop. I observed other blogs with full-sized headers on desktop. The mobile version shows a different header—well, a zoomed-in version of the header, I guess. Is there a .mobile html code I can input that will make the header look different, or maybe just have a separate header for mobile completely?
2. HTML widgets on Desktop, like the About Me widget, Twitter widget, Instagram widget, etc etc...they are usually found on the sidebar on desktop. On mobile, I want my HTML widgets to appear at the bottom when you scroll down to the very last part, underneath all the posts. I have seen other blogs do the same thing—on mobile, their sidebar (e.g. their different widgets) still appear, albeit this time at the very bottom of the page. Thus, blog posts on mobile occupy the full page. Any HTML codes that I can use to achieve this?
3. Finally, my nav bar on desktop consists of Home, Fashion, Beauty, Travel, Contact, About, plus my social media icons and search bar. It's a sticky nav bar and sticks to the very top of the page above header and stays always in sight at the top of the screen even when you scroll down. Once again I observed the nav bar of other blogs and on mobile, they condensed all their tabs into a single square like this:

Example of mobile navbar that I want

[image: xxx]

I want to create something like this, so when you click the icon with the 3 horizontal lines, something like this pops out:

Nav Bar Tabs

[image: xxx]

So yes—does anyone know how to make html widgets appear only at the bottom for mobile Blogger sites, and does anyone know how to make a navbar like this for mobile? Thank you!

Comment: Was to long for an answer, so I created a quick blog post: https://leesflamelayout.blogspot.co.at/2017/07/how-to-setup-your-custom-blogger-in-60_3.html. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a solution like Bootstrap.
http://getbootstrap.com/

This framework provides you mobile first and responsive functionality and they are pretty easy I think.